# How to input different size images as LSTM input in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

If I would like to input different size images like [1,512,256,3],[1,256,128,3],[1,128,64,3] as `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` inputs, what's the procedure?

Comment: `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` works for different lenghts, but not for different input sizes. With input size I mean the number of pixels feed to the cell at each time step. Is there a way to rescale the images to have all the same heigth or width?

Comment: Yes, actually I use this way to fix my problem, but it may be cause some error in my situation.

Comment: As far as I know there is not an easy way out for your problem with just one simple LSTM. You could try with 2-dimensional LSTMs, where you have a RNN structure both vertically and horizontally.